# Permission organisation in Managed Packages (Base+Extension)

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets, isv, managed-extension, permission-set-groups

When looking for detailed information on how the Salesforce Permission artifacts:

- Permission Sets
- Permission Set Groups
- Custom Permissions

can be best used in Managed Packages (across Base and Extension packages) I found a lot of "Doesn't work as expected" "Should work" etc.

**Can you list all the things that work, don't work, should be done, and shouldn't be done? And if that is too broad (sorry) maybe answer those specific questions:**

1. Can I put `PermsetGroups` in Base and have Extensions add `Permsets` and `CustomPerms`?
2. Can `PermsetGroups` in Extension re-bundle `Permsets` and CustomPerms?
3. Does the overall behavior differ between 1GP and 2GP Packages with a shared namespace?
4. Can Subscribers of the Base+Extension add, remove from packaged `PermsetGroups` or `Permsets`?

Comment: I will try to guess here a little, but I'd say 1. No. But Extensions can define their own Permission Set Groups. 2. What do you mean by `re-bundle`? You can't modify component (Permission Set Group) of your base package in extension; outside of that, you can do whatever you want. 3. Not that I know of 4.  No. Permission Sets are upgradeable so they're locked for editing by subscriber (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=packaging_packageable_components.htm&type=5)

Comment: Why not make this an answer with a few links to reference material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As with many new package components, I test everything in throwaway packages and only rely upon the behavior I can document. For that reason I can answer some, but not all, of your questions. I highly recommend testing with throwaway packages if you have finer-grained questions to which I don't have answers!

> Can I put PermsetGroups in Base and have Extensions add Permsets and CustomPerms?

Point of clarification: PSGs do not themselves contain Custom Permissions, but you can add PermSets to them that do.

Extension packages *cannot* package changes, such as adding a PermSet, to PSGs owned by base packages.

> Can PermsetGroups in Extension re-bundle Permsets and CustomPerms?

I believe your question is asking whether Extension PSGs can include PermSets owned by Base packages.

I do not know the answer to this question but will try the experiment in my throwaway packages and update here.

> Does the overall behavior differ between 1GP and 2GP Packages with a shared namespace?

I do not know the answer to this question.

> Can Subscribers of the Base+Extension add, remove from packaged PermsetGroups or Permsets?

Subscribers *can* add PermSets and Muting PermSets to managed PSGs. These subscriber changes do not impact, and are unaffected by, your package upgrades.

Subscribers *cannot* remove packaged PermSets from packaged PSGs.

---

A few other things I've learned about PSGs and packaging:

- You cannot change the label of a managed PSG.
- You can push-upgrade addition of a new PermSet too an existing PSG.
- You can push-upgrade removal of a PermSet from an existing PSG (it doesn't delete the PermSet, but removes from the PSG).
- Subscribers can compose your managed PermSets into their own unmanaged PSGs.
- You cannot delete managed PSGs.
- You can add unmanaged PermSets to managed PSGs via the Tooling or Metadata APIs.